# .js.php file extension adds on strange characters at end of file

Tags: php, javascript, apache

I have an Ubuntu server with a LAMP stack. I have some javascript that has a php include in the middle of it.

For the past year the code has worked fine, but now there is a strange set of characters appearing at the end when viewed in a browser:

`‹`

It seems to be connected to the .js.php file extension. I can simplify it down to:

- create test.php
- create test.xx.php
- create test.js.php
- edit the files with vi and put in the word `test`
- view them in a web browser
- http://example.com/test.php will display `test`
- http://example.com/test.xx.php will display `test`
- http://example.com/test.js.php will display `test ‹`

In notepad++ it show that there are a couple of extra characters that are actually there:

[image]

Its not a standard PHP openend bracket `<` which might make sense.

Hunting for '.js.php' or the characters in Google is pretty fruitless, so I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Please *download* (aot view in browser) http://example.com/test.php and view compare notepad++. Also please check file size and bytes for both and post. (I suspect they are all the same, but the different interpretation as text/html or text/js makes them appear different)

Comment: The downloaded source view from the browser for test.php just contains test and nothing else. The file size of both test.php and test.js.php is 5 bytes. If you rename the test.js.php to test.xx.php or test.js then it just displays 'test' in the browser source view.

Comment: @RichardW11 The only thing I could think of was the Byte Object Mark you have at the end of some UTF-8 files, or else the apache server was doing something, but I'm just guessing

Comment: The contents of the file is one line containing "test"? No newline to an empty line? The actual file, not the downloaded source view.

Comment: Try adding a header call at the beginning of the file `Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");`

Comment: @codewaggle Yes, literially, there's just test, no new line, no nothing, there isn't any `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: Did the header have any effect? Happens in multiple browsers? Dedicated server or could host have modified settings?

Comment: @codewaggle Header had no effect - am having a closer look at the http headers. Its on a dedicated server. Happens in FF, Chrome and IE8. There was a significant update failure with Plesk that's on the box earlier in the week which has knackered the Plesk admin.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14217/discussion-between-codewaggle-and-icc97)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too. The problem seems to be caused by the server gzipping the response incorrectly. (With mod_deflate of course).

Disabling mod_deflate through .htaccess resolved the issue for me - note that you can do something like this to disable per filetype:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.*\.js\.php$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

Strangely, I have two supposedly identical Ubuntu VMs - one where everything runs perfectly, and one where I need to disable mod_deflate. If anyone can figure why this is happening, I'd be interested to know!

Comment: Yep, that makes sense, I do have mod_deflate on. I'll test it today and check it fixes the problem then put this as the accepted answer. I'd made no modifications to the apache config - although I did have Plesk upgrade that screwed most of the Plesk installation, it definitely wasn't a change in the apache installation. It occurred on Ubuntu 10.04 if that helps.